# jQuery UI - what when droppable has to delete the dragged element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have an event that deletes the element it was working with. Looks something like this:

```
$('.droppable_slot').droppable({
    drop: function (event,ui) {
        // snipped lines of code
        delete_element(ui.draggable);
    }
);
```

And I get an error *a(this).data("draggable") is undefined* apparently because `delete_element()` deletes the element that drop event was working with (as it should). I don't know how to avoid this except to somehow run delete_element() only after the drop event (or .droppable() plugin) has finished running its function, but I don't know how to do that. I *could* suppress the error but I'd rather avoid that.

Comment: We need to see `// snipped lines of code`

Comment: I now replaced the entire snipped code with the actual comment line `// snipped lines of code` and it returned the same error, so it really isn't important what's there (and it's like 30 lines of calls to other functions in the script). The function delete_element() does something like `$('#dragged_item_container').html('');` so whatever was dragged gets wiped in the process, so I need to run that function after the drop event or it returns an error.

Comment: @L84, can you elaborate on why you want to empty the source container during the drop? Did you try a `clone` helper?

Comment: Try `$("#dragged_item-container").empty();` though I suspect it'l have the same problem. Can you post the contents of `delete_element`?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It's a function for changing the order in which pictures are displayed. When the user drags and drops a picture, the snipped lines change the order of pictures in an array, then call the function that empties the container and repopulates the array with the new pictures. It would take me hours to rework the function to move the elements around, it's way simpler to just delete them and add them again in different order.

Comment: @KevinB Same thing, although I kind of like empty() more. Cleaner, more readable.

Comment: @L84, you might be clearing the container too soon. As a quick check, can you add a call to `setTimeout()` with a short delay around the call to `delete_element()` and see if it fixes your problem? In any case, please consider creating a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces your problem, so we can see and experiment with the whole code.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yup, that works. 10ms timeout is enough, but I'll put 50ms just in case. Please write that as an answer so I can accept it. Then I'll change the title of the question so it matches the answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, you're clearing the source container too soon, before the drop operation has finished moving the source element to the target container.

Since there are no events triggered by the `droppable` widget after `drop`, delaying the clearing operation with [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) until the drop has completed can be a good workaround:

```
$(".droppable_slot").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        // Snipped lines of code...
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            delete_element(ui.draggable);
        }, 10);
    }
});
```

But this is a workaround, not a solution. What we actually need here is an event that occurs after the `drop` operation has completed. The `stop` event of the `draggable` widget might qualify. It will be hard to tell without seeing more of your code, though.

Comment: Thanks, that works. As for the `stop` event of the `draggable`, I'm not sure if it fires when the cursor stops moving or when the element is dropped, and if so, does it fire before or after `drop`. Your solution neatly sidesteps the issue. I see this as fault of jQuery UI - it should check whether the original element exists or at least catch the error.

Comment: @L84, nope, I would go the other way around and clone the source element so it can be dropped even if the original is removed along the way (the alternative, catching the error, does not leave you with many options, as there is no way to recover without a copy of the source element). Setting the `helper` option of the `draggable` to `clone` is supposed to deal with both problems, then again I don't have enough of your code to create a reliable fiddle for testing purposes :)

Comment: I've have this same issue, and I use clones, not the original element. The work around fix my issue, even with a 0 time out, which I find interesting.